# TypeError: write() got an unexpected keyword argument 'context' - Odoo v8 to Odoo v10 community

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-8, odoo-10

I've inherited `res.partner` class, and I have these two methods:

```
jour_id = fields.Many2one('account.journal', string='Journal', required=False,
    help="Default journal for damaged invoices")
acc_id = fields.Many2one('account.account', string='Account', 
    help="Default account used for invoices and lines from damaged invoices")
printer_fiscal = fields.Boolean(string='Manages fiscal printer',
    help='Indicates that the company can operate a fiscal printer')

@api.model
def create(self, vals): 
    """ To create a new record,
    adds a Boolean field to true
    indicates that the partner is a company
    """
    #if context is None:
        #context = {}
    ctx = self._context.copy()
    ctx.update({'create_company': True})
    return super(ResCompany, self).create(vals) 

@api.model
def write(self, values): 
    """ To write a new record,
    adds a Boolean field to true
    indicates that the partner is a company
    """
    #if context is None:
        #context = {}
    ctx = self._context.copy()
    ctx.update({'create_company': True})
    return super(ResCompany, self).write(values)
```

These two fields, are updated or created by these two functions `create` and `write`.

But when I try any of these, by editing the company, it throws me this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/http.py", line 638, in _handle_exception
return super(JsonRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception)
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/http.py", line 675, in dispatch
result = self._call_function(**self.params)
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/http.py", line 331, in _call_function
return checked_call(self.db, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/service/model.py", line 119, in wrapper
return f(dbname, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/http.py", line 324, in checked_call
result = self.endpoint(*a, **kw)
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/http.py", line 933, in __call__
return self.method(*args, **kw)
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/http.py", line 504, in response_wrap
response = f(*args, **kw)
File "/home/kristian/odoov10/odoo-10.0rc1c-20161005/odoo/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 862, in call_kw
return self._call_kw(model, method, args, kwargs)
File "/home/kristian/odoov10/odoo-10.0rc1c-20161005/odoo/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 854, in _call_kw
return call_kw(request.env[model], method, args, kwargs)
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/api.py", line 679, in call_kw
return call_kw_model(method, model, args, kwargs)
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/api.py", line 664, in call_kw_model
result = method(recs, *args, **kwargs)
TypeError: write() got an unexpected keyword argument 'context'
```

I think it's because of this `ctx = self._context.copy()` but I've seen other methods on v10 which have it declared this way, I don't know if I should remove it.

Any ideas on this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use **@api.multi** decorator in write method.

```
@api.multi
def write(self, values): 
    """ To write a new record,
    adds a Boolean field to true
    indicates that the partner is a company
    """
    #if context is None:
        #context = {}
    ctx = dict(self._context or {})
    ctx.update({'create_company': True})
    return super(ResCompany, self.with_context(ctx)).write(values)
```

Here 'Self' is a recordset you can't use **@api.one**  in write method.

You can find difference between 2 decorators from below link.

[When to use api.one and api.multi in odoo | openerp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27988565/when-to-use-api-one-and-api-multi-in-odoo-openerp)

Comment: Thank You very much

Comment: tks dude. what a simple yet frustating mistake :)))